# Controller not acting correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to code igniter but I've been watching many youtube videos and I'm starting to get the hang of the basics of it however after I do a test run on my registration form it goes to a white page with The requested URL /kowmanager/user/register was not found on this server. I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
function User() 
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();

    $this->load->model('User_model');
}

function index()
{
    $this->register();
}

function register()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean|strtolower|callback_usernameNotExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordConfirm', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_emailNotExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstName', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastName', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $firstName = $this->input->post('firstName');
        $lastName = $this->input->post('lastName');

        $registrationKey =  substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 5);

        $this->User_model->registerUser($username, $password, $email, $firstName, $lastName, $registrationKey);
    }

}

function usernameNotExists($username)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('usernameNotExists', ' That %s already exists inside the database!');

    if($this->User_model->checkExistsUsername($username))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function emailNotExists($username)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('emailNotExists', ' That %s already exists inside the database!');

    if($this->User_model->checkExistsEmail($email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

}
?>
```

View Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>KOW Manager Registration Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

    echo form_open($base_url . 'user/register');

    $username = array ('name'  => 'username', 'id' => 'username', 'value' => set_value('username'));
    $password = array ('name'  => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'value' => '');
    $passwordConfirm = array ('name'  => 'passwordConfirm', 'id' => 'passwordConfirm', 'value' => '');
    $email = array ('name'  => 'email', 'id' => 'email', 'value' => set_value('email'));
    $firstName = array ('name'  => 'firstName', 'id' => 'firstName', 'value' => set_value('firstName'));
    $lastName = array ('name'  => 'lastName', 'id' => 'lastName', 'value' => set_value('lastName'));

?>

<?php echo form_fieldset('User Information') ?>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="username">Username:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_input($username); ?></dd>

</dl>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="password">Password:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_password($password); ?></dd>

</dl>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_password($passwordConfirm); ?></dd>

</dl>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="email">Email Address:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_input($email); ?></dd>

</dl>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_input($firstName); ?></dd>

</dl>

<dl>

    <dt><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo form_input($lastName); ?></dd>

</dl>

<?php echo form_fieldset_close() ?>

<?php echo validation_errors() ?>

<dl class="submit">

    <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'register'), 'Register'); ?>

</dl>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit:

Here's my new code which is still doing the same thing.

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {

function User() 
{
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();

    $this->load->model('User_model');
}

function index()
{
    $this->register();
}

function register()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean|strtolower|callback_usernameNotExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordConfirm', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_emailNotExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstName', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastName', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $firstName = $this->input->post('firstName');
        $lastName = $this->input->post('lastName');

        $registrationKey =  substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 5);

        $this->User_model->registerUser($username, $password, $email, $firstName, $lastName, $registrationKey);

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('kowmanagement@kansasoutlawwrestling.com', 'KOW Management');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('KOW Manager Account Registration');
        $this->email->message('Hello '.$firstName.' '.$lastName.' Welcome to our website!<br /><br />You, or someone using your email address, has completed registration at '.myDomainName().'. You can complete registration by clicking the following link:<br /><br />' . anchor('http://www.'.myDomainName().'/manager/verify.php?userID='.$userID.'&verifyHash='.$verifyHash.'", http://www.'.myDomainName().'/manager/verify.php?userID='.$userID.'&verifyHash='.$verifyHash.''));
        $this->email->send();
    }

}

function registerConfirm()
{
    $registrationKey = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if ($registrationKey == '')
    {
        echo 'No registration key found in URL';
        exist(); 
    }

    $registrationConfirmed = $this->User_model->confirmRegistration($registrationKey);

    if ($registrationConfirmed)
    {
        echo 'You have successfully registered!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You have failed to register!';
    }
}

function usernameNotExists($username)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('usernameNotExists', ' That %s already exists inside the database!');

    if($this->User_model->checkExistsUsername($username))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function emailNotExists($username)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('emailNotExists', ' That %s already exists inside the database!');

    if($this->User_model->checkExistsEmail($email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function myDomainName() 
{
    $my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $my_domain = str_replace('www.', '', $my_domain);
    return $my_domain;
}

}
?>
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you add your routes to the controller?

Comment: If you mean $route['default_controller'] = "user";  then yes I did.

Comment: I'm confused about something: you use a different controller to call the view to render the registration form? also, why is your index method calling the registration method? and the last one, are you using CI 2 or CI 1.7? I think I may be able to help with a bit more clarity :)

Comment: You don't need to pass `base_url()` to your view. That method is available in views. Also, if you are submitting to the same method as is displaying the view, you can leave `form_open()` empty.

Comment: I'm using the latest version 2.02.

Comment: Can you post what you `base_url` is set to from config.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter routes by default are structured like this.

http://example.com/index.php/Controller/Function

If you don't have 'index.php' in your code it isn't going to be routed correctly unless you have a mod_rewrite rule setup in Apache.

try setting up your url like this

http://domain/index.php/user/register

and see what happens.

Check this out:
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Comment: Well I went to that last link and copied everything that was inside of that number 1 step and saved it and I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: What link exactly? And secondly, how is your webroot setup? Is the codeigniter project at the base or is it in a subfolder named '/kowmanager' if it's in a subfolder you'll need to structure it like this: 'http://domain/CISubfolder/index.php/user/register'

Comment: I'm working locally with wamp so I have localhost/kowmanager(my project)/system/

Comment: In that case, click this link: http://127.0.0.1/kowmanager/index.php/user/register/ and see what happens.

Comment: Oh I thought you were never getting to the form in the first place. See Chris Schmitz answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that what you are doing is this:

`mysite.com/kowmanager/user/register`
or
`mysite.com/index.php/kowmanager/user/register`

in either case

1) you are using the **knownmanager** Directory

2) you are using the controller **user**

3) you are calling the method '**register**'

You can check the following things:

It looks like you are using your user method as a constructor  if you are using CI 2 use

```
function __constructor() {
  parent::__constructor();
}
```

as your constructor.

also you are not calling the view in this controller, are you using a different controller to call the view? I would create a new method called registration_form and call the view from there:

```
$data['data'] = array();
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

In this case what you would do is use the following url

```
mysite.com/kowmanager/index.php/user/registration_form/
```

Then when the form is submitted it will call the validation method.

I'm not sure if you are loading form_validation before using it

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I also recommend the series of videos: CodeIgniter from Scratch http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

Answer (score 2):

Try setting you base_url. If you're working locally and using MAMP or XAMP, it would be something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/kowmanager';
```

Comment: That gave me the Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888.

Comment: localhost:8888 might not be where you actual development environment is.  Are you working locally or on a server?  What URL do you have to enter to access your app?  You have to enter the base URL to your root folder for the application.

Comment: I am working locally so when I go to the URL http://localhost/kowmanager it correctly goes to my registration form

Comment: Then you should set your base_url to that.  I updated my answer accordingly.